# invalid conversion from cql::cql_byte_t* {aka unsigned char*} to const char*

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, char, arrays

I am trying to extract few bytes from a byte array in C++.. I am using `ntohs` to extract first two bytes which is my `schemaId`.. So I created a method in `FileMapMgr` class that will be doing the conversion using `ntohs`..

```
uint16_t newSchemaId;

for (size_t i = 0; i < result->column_count(); ++i) {
    cql::cql_byte_t* data = NULL;
    cql::cql_int_t size = 0;
    result->get_data(i, &data, size);

        int index=0;

        // this line gives me exception
        newSchemaId = FileMapMgr::get_uint16(&data[index]);
        index += 2;

        flag = false;
}
```

Below is the method in FileMapMgr class which I am calling from the above method-

```
uint16_t FileMapMgr::get_uint16(const char* buffer)
{
    if (buffer)
    {
        return ntohs(*reinterpret_cast<const uint16_t*>(buffer));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And below is the exception I am getting -

```
error: invalid conversion from cql::cql_byte_t* {aka unsigned char*} to const char* [-fpermissive]
```

Is there anything I am missing here?

I am using [libcql](https://github.com/mstump/libcql) library for Cassandra here. So this `cql::cql_byte_t*` is coming from libcql Cassandra library..

Any help will be appreciated on this..

Comment: _'Is there anything I am missing here?'_ Yes, a `const` or `const_cast<>` most probably!

Comment: Thanks g-makulik for the suggestion... Where should I add this casting? I don't want to modify my FileMapMgr method code.. Is there any way we can pass the information from my for loop to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is complaining that it cannot convert a `cql::cql_byte_t*` into `const char*`. This is apparently because a `cql::cql_byte_t` is aliased to `unsigned char`.

You can either cast the pointer before you call the method, or add a new method to take an `const unsigned char *`.

For the former:

```
        // this line gives me exception
        newSchemaId = FileMapMgr::get_uint16(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&data[index]));
```

For the latter:

```
uint16_t FileMapMgr::get_uint16(const unsigned char* buffer)
{
    return get_uint16(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(buffer));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot jxh for the suggestion.. I can use either of your above suggestion right? I am thinking to use former one example you gave me.. I am not inclined towards changing the FileMapMgr code.. Let me try this out.. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, either one. But the second one is not changing the original function, but adding a new one. You are very welcome.